# product name change

Tags: iphone, rename, product

I have created a app with the name "sampleApp".In that, I want to change the name of the file "sampleApp.app" which is present under product category in the project navigator pane of the left side of the xcode.How do I change this name to "myApp.app". I dono how to change this.Pls help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your target and then choose the Build Settings pane. There, look for a "Product Name" key and assign to it the desired value. See also this image:

[image]

You could also rename entirely your project as an alternative.

Comment: It works for me...Thank you very much sergio...I having one more doubt.How can I add one more product name for the same project...?

Comment: do you mean how to add a new target to your project? just below the targets list you find a big button called "add new target". then you can assign the sources you need to this target... if I have not understood your question, please elaborate on it...